# display array inside array in a table (view)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How can I display an array of array in a table (view) ?

```
matrix = Array.new(rows){Array.new(cols){0}}
```

like that:

```
0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0
```

Answer (score 1):

```
matrix = Array.new(3){Array.new(4){0}}

puts matrix.map {|x| x.join(' ')}

0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0
```

Comment: but I want put this matrix in a view!